# How to change the text of a BarButtonItem on the NavigationBar?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uinavigationbar, uibuttonbaritem

I am trying to create a list of items that can be edited.  Something like this:

[image]

To that end, I added a NavigationBar to the top of the view, then added 2 Bar Button Items in XCode designer.  I set the identifier for the button on the left to Add, for the button on the right to Edit.

When I click the Edit, I want to change the text to Done.  I've tried various ways, e.g. `btnEdit.Title = "Done"`, but it simply doesn't take.

I've seen several blog posts recommending .SetTitle, but UIButtonBarItem doesn't have that method (at least in MonoTouch).

So, how can I change the title of the Edit button?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I resolved it. The key was I was setting the identifier of the Edit button to a system value (e.g. UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit) and you can't change the text of those (makes sense now). I changed the identifier back to Custom and setting .Title worked fine.

Comment: Really helpful. Thanks :)

Comment: Godddd I was stuck on this for an embarrassingly long time.. Thanks!!

Answer (score 10):

Why don't you try changing the `navigationItem.rightbarButtonItem` property ?

**1.** Set up two buttons, one for edit and one for done

```
 UIBarButtonItem*editButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(editAction)];

 UIBarButtonItem*doneButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(doneAction)];
```

**2.** And wherever necessary, in `editAction` preferrably change the `rightBarButtonItem` like:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=doneButton;
```

And if you need the `editButton` back

```
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=editButton;
```

Comment: Upon changing `rightBarButtonItem`, for some reason, actions attached to both buttons aren't working.

Answer (score 5):

```
if ([self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title isEqualToString:@"Edit"]) 
{
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title= @"Done";
}
```

hope this helps. happy coding :)

Comment: You can't use == to compare strings.  You should use isEqualToString: instead.

Comment: please accept the answer if it helped, so as to guide others who have the same problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Works for me like this as **UIBarButtonItem *btnEdit**; is class memember in .h;

```
btnEdit = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(btnEditClicked)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnEdit;
//[btnEdit release];
```

Now selector called would be:

```
-(void)btnEditClicked
{
  if([btnEdit.title isEqualToString:@"Edit"])
  {
    [btnEdit setTitle:@"Done"];
  }
  else
  {
    [btnEdit setTitle:@"Edit"];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Control drag from bar button to file (using assistant editor), create outlet (in this case, its called "barButton".  Then, add this:

Swift 3.0:

```
self.barButton.title = "New title"
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-new the button like below . .

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "title", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(actionMethod))
```